# Removing factors with Unique Counts less than X

Tags: r

I am trying to remove factors that have unique counts with less than 5. I tried both approaches using apply and subsetting, but have not found a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

```
df <- data.frame(letters=letters[1:7],
                 numbers=seq(1:25))

levels(df$letters)
## [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g"

#Attempt 1
df[apply(df$letters, 1, function(x) row(unique(x))) < 5]
#Attempt 2
df <- df[which(unique(df$letters < 5)),]
```

Comment: `df[df$letters %in% names(table(df$letters))[table(df$letters) > 5],]`

Comment: Your code doesn't run on the current version of R (the variables in the data frame are of different lengths and can't recycle evenly). In dplyr, it's just a grouped filter, though: `df %>% group_by(letters) %>% filter(n() >= 5)`

Comment: Thanks d.b. this worked. If you put it in the solutions, Ill give credit. Alistaire, I'll check into this. This could be an issue waiting.